# Why "fiat lux" and not "sit lux"?

Tags: grammar-choice, tenses, bible

The Vulgate reads:

> Dixitque Deus: fiat lux. Et facta est lux.

But I would have expected:

> Dixitque Deus: sit lux. Et fuit lux.

This is based on scientific texts, where "let x" be is rendered as *sit x*.

Would my version still be correct Latin? How does it differ from the first?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps the following comparison makes this understandable:

> *sit lux* ≈ may light exist
> *fiat lux* ≈ may light come into existence

The English translation "let there be light" is gives a slightly different impression than the Latin *fiat lux*.
In Latin the wish or order is for light to come or to be made, not for it to be.

The choice of *fiat* is paralleled by *facta* in the next sentence.
One possible English translation would have been: "May light be made. And light was made."
That would arguably have been less poetic.
Perhaps someone can comment on the English translation tradition and why it ended up speaking of the light being instead of coming or being made.
For what it's worth, in the Finnish translations light comes, so the English wording is not used globally.

The perfect tense of *fuit* sounds odd and the meaning of the sentence unclear.
This tense often signifies the completion of an act, making it better suited for *facta est* than *fuit*.
It depends on context, but *fuit lux* can well be closer to "light has been" than "light was".

Comment: 'Lux sit' is actually the Latin motto of my graduate school alma mater, the University of Washington, Seattle (which I believe you visited several years ago).

Comment: @cnread Interesting! I have indeed been at UW a couple of times. To me that sounds like a wish for light to continue to exist rather than the creation of light in the famous Genesis scene. If there is a story to what the motto tries to signal, that might make a nice answer.

Comment: Well, I had heard of and read some very creative attempts to justify it during my time there; but the general agreement, I think, is that it was just sloppy Latin and should have used fiat instead of sit. Still, it does sort of works for that university, its location/climate, and student body (especially if the subjunctive is read as potential instead of jussive). Maybe there's something about it on the university's website. I'll take a look later.

Comment: @cnread Maybe it's pejorative: "There *might* be "light" here, but then again, given the Latin skills, there might not!" (Teasing, teasing!)

Answer (score 8):

It's just barely possible it's simpler than that. First, note that the Hebrew *does* use a verb corresponding to *sit* rather than *fiat*:

> וַיֹּאמֶר אֱלֹהִים יְהִי אוֹר וַיְהִי־אוֹר׃
> *wayyomer ĕlohîm: "yəhî ʾôr" wayəhî-ʾôr.*

יְהִי *yəhî* is a 3rd m. sg. jussive of היה 'to be'.

The Septuagint turns this into the following:

> καὶ εἶπεν ὁ Θεός· γενηθήτω φῶς· καὶ ἐγένετο φῶς.

γενηθήτω is the 3rd sg. aorist imperative of γίγνομαι 'to become'. Latin's 3rd person imperative is rarely used for most verbs, and *gigno*, the cognate of γίγνομαι, is pretty cumbersome and certainly more marked than γίγνομαι is in Greek, so *fiat* is a more than fair rendering of that; the Vulgate clearly closely follows the Septuagint here.

(This does mean that *fiat* isn't acting as the passive of *facio* here but just has its own meaning of 'to become' (*factus est*, too, is the active perfect of semi-deponent *fio*, not the passive of *facio*), but it's not clear that this is a line Jerome or any contemporary speaker of Latin would have drawn.)

So why didn't the Septuagint use a form of εἰμί 'to be'? It did! εἰμί is suppletive, with γίγνομαι supplying its aorist stem!

Was Jerome simply unaware of that? Probably not, admittedly, and he certainly did also know Hebrew and have access to the Hebrew version of Genesis, so his choice of *fiat* is almost certainly a conscious decision made for the reasons Joonas discussed (and the fact that he *didn't* use *gignatur* is actually a point in favour of that). But I thought it was an interesting observation.

Comment: "his choice of fiat is almost certainly a conscious decision" – yes, but it's worth mentioning that the author of the Vetus Latina had made [the same decision.](https://books.google.de/books?id=IsZ4ayaer-QC&pg=PA7)

Comment: Wait… “ĕlohîm” translates to “gods,” plural, no?

Comment: @PierrePaquette It's a form that looks plural but is used for the singular God (with singular verbs etc.).

Comment: @PierrePaquette Yes, it's a *pluralis maiestatis/excellentiae*.